# Spanner SQL Filtering by Less Than on Tuples

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

Is there any way to achive `<, >, etc` comparisons in the `WHERE` clause of a Spanner SQL query where the values compared are not scalar but tuples/structs?

For example, say we have a table `users` (intentionally unrealistic schema)

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    is_special BOOL NOT NULL,
    registered_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
) PRIMARY KEY (is_special DESC, registered_on DESC)
```

The natural sort order of the PK index is then `is_special DESC, registered_on DESC`.

I want select a range of rows starting with a specific row in that PK index (i.e. from a cursor):

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE (is_special, registered_on) < (@cursor.is_special, @cursor.registered_on)
LIMIT 100
```

That's not allowed by Spanner SQL because the tuple is treated as a STRUCT type and STRUCT types do not allow the `<` comparison. Is there any other way to achieve this?

With the Read API, I can query a range by using a KeyRange and providing the PK of the row I want to start the query from, but I'd like to achieve the same in SQL.

Comment: I did not find a specific example regarding this , but the official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/query-syntax#using_structs_with_select) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/structs#using_struct_objects_as_bound_parameters_in_sql_queries) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to write the query using individual fields.  This relies on the fact that column is_special is not nullable.

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE (is_special < @cursor.is_special) OR (is_special = @cursor.is_special AND registered_on < @cursor.registered_on)
LIMIT 100
```

Just for completeness; if column is_special is nullable then it gets a uglier.

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE (is_special < @cursor.is_special) OR ((is_special = @cursor.is_special OR (is_special IS NULL AND @cursor.is_special IS NULL)) AND registered_on < @cursor.registered_on)
LIMIT 100
```

Additional comment.  The query has a `LIMIT` clause but no `ORDER BY` clause.  This is legal but unusual and it looks like a bug given that the query is paging results.

I think the query should have the following clause:

```
ORDER BY is_special, registered_on
```

The reason is as follows:

If a SQL query does not have an `ORDER BY` clause then it does not provide any row ordering guarantee.  In practice you will observe ordering in Spanner results even without an `ORDER BY` clause but no order is guaranteed and you should not rely on it.  However, if a query has an `ORDER BY` and Spanner uses an index that provides the required order then Spanner will not explicitly sort the data.  Therefore you need not worry about the performance or memory impact of including `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Ah yeah, meant to include the `ORDER BY is_special, registered_on`.

Isn't the use of the `OR` problematic when trying to use the index from `PRIMARY KEY (is_special DESC, registered_on DESC)`, i.e. it won't be able to use the sort order of the index? I've tested with scenarios using `OR` in that manner and end up with full table scans.

Comment: That's a good point.  The query becomes more complex but but it should help to add a conjunction on the leading column:

SELECT * FROM users
WHERE (is_special < @cursor.is_special) OR (is_special = @cursor.is_special registered_on < @cursor.registered_on)
AND (is_special <= @cursor.is_special)
ORDER BY is_special DESC, registered_on DESC
LIMIT 100

Comment: Oops, I did not use parenthesis properly with that query text.  This fixes the parenthesis:
`SELECT * FROM users WHERE (is_special <= @cursor.is_special) AND ((is_special < @cursor.is_special) OR (is_special = @cursor.is_special registered_on < @cursor.registered_on))
ORDER BY is_special DESC, registered_on DESC 
LIMIT 100
`.

Unfortunately the benefit of the extra filter will be limited because the leading column is of `BOOL` type (the scan will start from either the first `FALSE` or the first `TRUE`).

Comment: I looked more closely at this.  You actually do not need the additional predicate.  Spanner is smart enough to use the index to seek on each element of the OR so as to get all the qualifying rows without performing a full scan.

Comment: Thanks @Campbell-Fraser, really helpful to have a Spanner insider comment on this. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Campbel-Fraser It seems to mean that we don't have to rewrite the filter as described in "Indexing Equivalent Logic" of this page. Right? https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page